# Best approach to wrap Apache Log4j into a custom class. Keep in memory logging management

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I know that there are some answers already on wrapping logger around here, but none of them were satisfactory. I want to wrap Apache Log4j and also to keep an in memory management of errors (like class who thrown that error, reason and a count) and the scope is multiple: not to spam the log with the same error multiple times, to provide an close to user readable way of the root error cause, to have an overview classifications of errors and from where they came from etc.
Has anyone developed something similar? Is there any open source framework that can do that already?

Comment: Consider  looking into a new backend for slf4j instead.

Comment: What do you mean by a new backend? I was hoping for a nicer / simpler solution